# En plotly ¿Por qué los valores de las matrices, en el gráfico adoptan valores diferentes?

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, 3d

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fast':[1,2,2],'Slow':[3,4,5],'TEA':[18.23,9.76,7.30]})

x = np.linspace(df.Fast.min(), df.Fast.max(), len(df.Fast.unique()))
y = np.linspace(df.Slow.min(), df.Slow.max(), len(df.Slow.unique()))
X , Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = interpolate.griddata((df.Fast, df.Slow), df.TEA, (X,Y))
Z[np.isnan(Z)] = df.TEA.mean()

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=X),go.Surface(y=Y),go.Surface(z=Z)])

fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True,
                              highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True))

fig.update_layout(title='results_3D1', autosize=True,
              scene_camera_eye=dict(x=1.87, y=0.88, z=-0.64),
              width=500, height=500,
              margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90),
              scene = dict(xaxis = dict(nticks=8, range=[0,4]),
                 yaxis = dict(nticks=8, range=[0,4]),
                 zaxis = dict(nticks=21, range=[0,20]))
              )

fig.show()
```

Estoy trabajando con plotly y tengo inconvenientes para que los puntos de los gráficos adopten los mismos valores de las matrices

Comment: Yo lo veo correcto

Comment: podrías enviarme la imagen del gráfico para ver si tal tengo algún inconveniente con el IDE

Comment: Puedes probarlo en este [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OOZuFLgv2d-xirWRaceAapkI_21vf_0m?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Christian mire el notebook pero si ves los valores de los puntos del gráfico para el eje "x" e "y" no coinciden con los valores de la matriz

Comment: la matriz contiene los valors de `[1,2]`, `[18.x, 11.73]` y algo mas, no recuerdo, creo que debes de verificar los valores de la matriz

Comment: fijate que no se cumplen para el eje y = 'Slow':[3,4,5]